# Why are MonoGame's Rectangle class fields immutable in F#?

Tags: f#, monogame

```
    let rect = new Rectangle(x, y, sprite.Width, sprite.Height)
    rect.X <- 888
```

The second line fails in F#, but in C# the assignment works. I am not sure why.

Comment: In what way does it fail? What is the full type name of rectangle? I'm guessing not the struct from System.Drawing in the full .net framework.

Comment: The interesting thing here is that the [`Rectangle`](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Rectangle.cs) is a struct and [probably shouldn't be muttable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/) but it is and always has been (in both MonoGame and XNA). I'd argue that F# is helping by making it clear that something is wrong here where as C# hides the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Rectangle` is a struct rather than a class. You can have that line work as you'd expect if you mark the value with `mutable`:

```
let mutable rect = new Rectangle(10, 21, 10, 21)
rect.X <- 888
```

This is actually quite interesting, as F# makes the value-type semantics of structs more visible compared to what C# does.

`rect.X <- 888` does not really mutate the field, rather it updates `rect` with a new value of the struct with the X field modified. So you can imagine it does an equivalent of `rect <- { rect with X = 888 }`. At that point it's quite clear why the compiler wants to see `mutable` there.

I wonder why F# designers didn't prohibit assignment syntax for structs and go with something similar to the record syntax. Probably they didn't want to make it too different compared to C#.

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler is probably saying,

> A value must be mutable in order to mutate the contents or take the
>   address of a value type, e.g. 'let mutable x = ...'

In F#, `let` creates an immutable variable (i.e. a value). The compiler enforces this by not letting you mutate it. You must write `let mutable` to get an equivalent variable declaration to what you had in C#.

Note that if Rectangle was a reference type, F# wouldn't complain, because you'd be modifying what is referenced by the value, not the value itself. In the case of a value type (like Mono's Rectangle), the identifier bound to the value is the value itself, so you cannot mutate it.